# Theme installation error "The parent theme could not be found"

Tags: themes, parent-theme

I downloaded this theme from wordpress:

https://theme.wordpress.com/themes/celsius/

If I want to install it, I am getting always the following error:

> The parent theme could not be found. You will need to install the
>   parent theme, isola-wpcom, before you can use this child theme.

I already tried to install the theme "Isola" but that don't help.
Searching for "isola-wpcom" on google also gave me no results.

Does anybody has an idea?
Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I already tried to install the theme "Isola" but that don't help. Searching for "isola-wpcom" on google also gave me no results.

I think you need this:
https://wordpress.org/themes/isola/

Really simple some themes do have some requirements, either other themes or plugins. However, after some checking, I cannot find the theme "celsius".

If we check the source code from https://celsiusdemo.wordpress.com/
And precisely the style.css you will get the feedback the theme name is **Isola**.

```
/*
Theme Name: Isola
Theme URI: https://wordpress.com/themes/isola/
Author: Automattic
Author URI: https://wordpress.com/themes/
Description: Isola is a fresh, clean slate for your best works, perfect for showcasing your writing, photographs, or videos in a bold way. Its primary menu and widget area are tucked behind a handy button, giving your content plenty of room to breathe, and Isola looks beautiful regardless of the device or screen size.
Version: 1.0.6-wpcom
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Text Domain: isola
Tags: blog, lifestream, photography, clean, white, light, one-column, custom-background, custom-colors, custom-header, custom-menu, rtl-language-support, translation-ready, journal, photoblogging, simple, featured-images, fixed-menu, post-formats, infinite-scroll, fixed-layout, responsive-layout

This theme, like WordPress, is licensed under the GPL.
Use it to make something cool, have fun, and share what you've learned with others.

Isola is based on Underscores http://underscores.me/, (C) 2012-2016 Automattic, Inc.
*/
```

Comment: First, thanky you for your answer. Unfortunately, like I've written above, is the theme "Isola" already installed and activated, but the installation-error with the orther theme "celsius" remains the same. Do you have any other ideas? I think the problem is the missing "-wpcom" ending...

Comment: The theme *celsius* is actually **Isola** as I found out @DJW.